# Magento configurable product with unlimited options

Tags: php, magento, webshop, configurable-product

I have a Magento webshop and would like to have a product that is configurable with unlimited attribute values for the size of the product. I have a piece of fabric that can be ordered per mm. So someone can order 50mm but also 50000mm there really is no limit. How can I can accomplish this within Magento? I don't think it's a good idea to add thousands of options as attribute values in the drop down for the configurable product?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your price is to vary depending on the length that the user inputs. You'll want to use a "Custom Option" on a Simple Product to allow the user to choose the length in mm. But the kicker is how to get the variable pricing. I found this plugin that might be of use to you: http://www.micosolutions.com/magento-extensions/advanced-variation-pricing-for-magento

Note that I'm in no way affiliated with the plugin developer - I was just curious about how to solve your problem and found this via Google.

Comment: This example of the above mentioned plugin seems to apply best to your use-case: [http://demo.micosolutions.com/avp/magento-two-variation-length-pricing-text-field-example.html](http://demo.micosolutions.com/avp/magento-two-variation-length-pricing-text-field-example.html)